# What's going on here, Buffer-Overflow skips couple bytes

Tags: c, ubuntu, buffer-overflow

So I'm working through the book "Hacking - the art of exploitation", but I don't know what's going on here. The program has a buffer with no length handling so it can overflow. I overwrote the return address of the stack frame to an address, where some instructions are located. However, I only get a segmentation error. I disabled the stack protector in gcc.

Are there other protection variables? Or what's going on here? And why are the highlighted bytes not overflown?

[image]

Comment: It could be that your hardware/memory management distinguishes between instruction memory and data memory and refuses to execute instructions in data memory.

Comment: What were you expecting to get? What instruction are located there? what is the program? What buffer? How do you overwrite the return address in the stack frame? What's the assembly output of your program?

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried different instructions, from shell code which opens a root shell to print instruction. The Program is in the book, it is the tinyweb program. Buffer is a char[], I haven't looked at the assembly output yet..

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Is this common?

Comment: @Chiray: According to the [Ubuntu security documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#nx) it looks like the stack is marked non-executable in modern versions of Ubuntu, and in fact the most recent versions of the kernel ignore any attempts by the BIOS to disable this feature.